# Convert array of JSON to array of Activerecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

I have an array of JSON strings. How do I convert them to an array of Activerecord models?

My current code looks like this, and I'd to not iterate it one by one:

```
jsons = ['{"id": 1, "field1" : "value1"}'] #this is an array of jsons
models = [] #i want an array of models back

jsons.each do |json|
            if(json == nil)
                next
            end

            begin
                hash = JSON.parse(json)
            rescue
                next
            end

            model = className.new
            model.attributes = hash
            model.id = hash["id"]
            models << model
end
```

Comment: The data is neither valid JSON nor Ruby Hash.

Answer (score 3):

You should do:

```
models = jsons.compact.map { |json| Klass.new(JSON.parse(json)) }
```

where `Klass` is the `ActiveRecord model class`

### EDIT

Based on the comments, you don't want to mass assign ID's, it could really get clumsy, it's better to leave rails to generate it for you, non mass assignment is:

```
models = jsons.compact.map { |json| Klass.new(JSON.parse(json).except(:id, "id")) }
```

`:id, "id"` is because I am not sure if the parsed JSON uses symbol or strings as keys

Comment: After fixing the JSON to actually be JSON, this could work. I'm pretty sure the `id` attribute is not mass assignable, though. You might need something like `Klass.new(JSON.parse(json)) { |m| m.id = json.id }`

Comment: @maček I can work around that by putting attr_accessible :id in my model class, right?

Comment: @HenleyChiu mass assigning id is not a good idea, its better to leave it to rails to generate it for you, so I have updated my answer to reveal this

Comment: The JSON has the ID as well, and I want the converted model to have the same ID. Does your code do that? I tested it and it doesn't seem to have the ID filled.

Comment: @HenleyChiu, you can populate the id using the block as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @HenleyChiu you need to be certain the ID from the json is always unique, and has not been previously chosen in the DB and it is non-nil